# Latex: use Pirat font for the King's fig instead of Skaknew King's fig

Tags: chess, xskak, chessfss

I'm using chessfss together with xskak package to make game's annotation, my favourite chess font is skaknew, but the figfont for the King look a bit complicated.
Is there anyway to use Pirat font for the King fig?

Thanks
p/s: I added a picture which I took from quality chess's book. The King's fig look simple very close to pirat font, so I came up with the idea.

```
[![\documentclass\[parskip\]{scrartcl}
\usepackage\[LSF,T1\]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bookman}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage\[utf8\]{inputenc}

\pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map}
\setchessboard{
    boardfontfamily=skaknew,
}
\setfigfontfamily{skaknew}

\newcommand\piratking{\makealetter\fontfamily{pirat}\selectfont\cfss@symking}
\renewcommand\symking\{{piratking}}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.  e4  e5 2.Ke2}
\chessboard
\end{document}]
```

[image: This is my false attemp.]

[image: I take a picture from Quality's chess book. The King's fig look simple and very close to pirat font]

Comment: I presume those are backslashes in the real document. Sorry I can't answer.

Comment: Make a complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: Sorry. I'm writing on the go. I will submit a complete example when I get home. Thanks. 

Comment: In my opinion it won't fit at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the king with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cfss@king@@LSB{{\fontencoding{LSF}\fontfamily{pirat}\selectfont K}}
\makeatother
```

But the result is rather awful. Compared to the other pieces the king is to narrow, the line width differ, the style is different, the placement too.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mrs @UlrikeFischer. You're right about the styling. I will try to adjust fontsize to see if it could be better. Or else, maybe I will just abandon the idea.